# Can I change the behaviour of commands in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to write a script which should execute when I fire a rm command in linux.
script should do the following stuff
-- when i execute rm command, files which are removed should be moved to one specific folder ( It should work as recycle bin in Microsoft). And after one day all files in that specific folder(recycle bin) should be removed.

Comment: First of all it's a bad idea to alter the behaviour of the `rm` command. But you can install additional app like `trash-cli`, use it to move stuff to the recycle bin and then create a crob job for emptying the recycle bin once a day at particular time.

Comment: @Kiloreux :
I have written a script as below,
script name : /home/user/remove.ksh
-----------------------------------
#!/bin/ksh
ARGS=$#
VAR=$@
echo $VAR
for i in echo $VAR ; do
    mv $i /home/user/recycle_bin/
done
-----------------------------------
and set an alias for this script in .profile as,
alias remove = "/home/user/remove.ksh"

and used this as rm command 
eg. remove test1.txt test2.txt

but it will not be useful when i want to remove whole directory.

Comment: You *could* log on as root and replace /usr/bin/rm with your own program